# Github and vue.Js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, github, deployment, build

I'm a beginner and I'm learning javascript and vueJs.

i want to deploy my first vuejs app but it's impossible.
I lost hours but I can't do it anymore. I have to ask for help.

When i deploy, i have a blank page.

My vue.config.js:

```
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({   transpileDependencies: true,  
publicPath:process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' 
?'/My-repo/'  
: '/'
})
```

And My deploy.bat file:

```
# abort on errors
set -e

# build
npm run build

# navigate into the build output directory
cd dist

# if you are deploying to a custom domain
# echo 'www.example.com' > CNAME

git init
git add -A
git commit -m 'deploy'

# if you are deploying to https://<USERNAME>.github.io
# git push -f git@github.com:<USERNAME>/<USERNAME>.github.io.git main

# if you are deploying to https://<USERNAME>.github.io/<REPO>
git push -f git@github.com:myUsername/myRepository.git master:gh-pages

cd -
```

thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you followed the official guide? https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#github-pages=

Comment: yes! exept that i use a bat file.
If i do:
"npm run build"
then i go in dist folder and execute 
"serve -s dist"
it is work.
But not with git hub!

Comment: Have you configured your publishing source within github pages? https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site

You'll want to set that to /dist if that's where the build task is publishing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers guys.

If it can help others.

On **Ubuntu**, with VSCode I created the deploy.sh file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

# abort on errors
set -e

# build
npm run build

# navigate into the build output directory
cd dist
    
git init
git add -A
git commit -m 'deploy'

# if you are deploying to https://<USERNAME>.github.io/<REPO>
git push -f git@github.com:<USERNAME>/<REPO>.git master:gh-pages


cd -
```

then I entered following code in terminal of vscode:

```
chmod +x deploy.sh
```

then

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "<Your@email.com>"
```

- copy the key
- go to settings in Github
- Add new SSH Key

Then go to package.json and add "deploy":"sh deploy.sh" in scripts:

```
"scripts":{
"deploy":"sh deploy.sh"
},
```

then in Terminal:

```
npm run deploy
```

In github go to:

- your repository
- chose "gh-pages" branch
- go to settings
- go to Pages
- chose -> Branch: gh-pages
- Then click on the link.

Thank you everyone and have a nice day.
And sorry for my poor English ;)